# How to modify field rendering behaviour based on state of other fields of model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, django-forms

Let's assume that I have following models:

```
class ScoutBook(models.Model):
       troop = models.ForeignKey('Dictionary', limit_choices_to={'type' : 'Troop'},  related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)

class Dictionary(models.Model): 
     name = models.CharField(max_length=CHAR_FIELD_MAX_LEN, verbose_name="Nazwa")
     active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Aktywny")
     type = models.CharField(max_length=CHAR_FIELD_MAX_LEN, choices=DICTIONARY_CHOICES)
```

and I want to implement following logic:

when creating ScoutBook allow users to select only active troops, and when editing allow to select active troops *or allow user to leave value unchanged* (even if the troop is inactive). If I use `limit_choices_to = {..., 'active' = True}` troop that is inactive is absent from combo box in django admin.

So to be clear: let's assume that there are four troops in this system: `Troop1`, `Troop2` and `InactiveTroop`, `InactiveTroop2`. On model creation I would like user to be able to choose `Troop1` and `Troop2`. If model has troop field set to `InactiveTroop2`, I would like user to be able to choose between `InactiveTroop2`, `Troop1` and `Troop2`.

I was looking at the django forms api and I didn't found obvious way do this. Moreover, in the application I'm developing there will be many such fields and many such models --- so solution must be pain free. I would rather not create new Form class for every model. I will be using mostly django admin to enable editing the database, and some read only views that will just list entries.

Ideally I would like to encapsulate this functionality in some custom field --- but fields have access to model instance on validate and save phase --- so I dont have access to it when I produce formfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I had to hook into ModelForm creation. Attached Form inspects it's fields and if specific conditions are met it replaces model field queryset.

```
    class DictionayModelForm(ModelForm):
        def __init__(self, *largs, **kwargs):
            super(DictionayModelForm, self).__init__(*largs, **kwargs)
            if self.instance and self.instance.pk is not None:
                for f in self.instance._meta.fields:
                    if isinstance(f, models.ForeignKey) and issubclass(f.rel.to, Dictionary):
                        model_field = self.fields[f.name]
                        value = getattr(self.instance, f.name, None)
                        if value and value not in model_field.choices:
                            model_field.queryset = Dictionary.objects.filter(Q(**f.rel.limit_choices_to) | Q(id = value.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something you want to do in a form, not in the object itself. Create a ModelForm and override the [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) like this:

```
from django import forms

class ScoutBookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    troop = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Troop.objects.filter(active=True))
    class Meta:
        model = ScoutBook
```

You can also [override the `clean` method of ScoutBook](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) to ensure it cannot ever be saved with an inactive Troop, though that may have some unintended consequences (e.g., you wouldn't be able to update a ScoutBook in the admin if the troop had gone inactive at some point in the past).

Comment: Well I speciffically said that I would rather not have specific forms. And I want to be able to cope with Troops going inactive by allowing selecting Inactive troop if it has been already attached to that Model.

Comment: Sorry, I saw "didn't found obvious way do this". Creating a modelform is the standard way to do it in Django and it's a matter of a couple of lines of code. Otherwise you can do it in the clean() method of the models. I guess you could create a Mixin, but that sounds like more work than creating forms.

Comment: Well I might end creating some kind of base class for model forms that will do some logic in __init__ but still hooking somewhere into Field/Model api would be less code :).